# Angular 6 radio button is not checked

Tags: angular

I have the following piece of code,

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 mb-5">
  <label>Versioning</label><br/>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="versioning" value="Enabled" ngModel #versioning="ngModel">
    <label class="form-check-label">Enabled</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="versioning" checked=”checked” value="Disabled" ngModel #versioning="ngModel">
    <label class="form-check-label">Disabled</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the "Disabled" radio button, selected by default. I tried giving checked, `checked="checked"`, `[checked]="true"`, `checked="true"` but nothing works.

I searched for similar questions in Stack Overflow and didn't found any answer.

Comment: What is the `#versioning` used for? Because the problem is that the empty ngModel is interfering with the `checked` attribute.

Comment: The model is the single point of truth. Bind your inputs to a model with `[(ngModel)]="versioning" removed the checked=”checked” and the #versioning="ngModel", and just set the value of YourComponent.versioning to 'Enabled' or 'Disabled'. https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. It works!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **disabled** instead of ***value="Disabled"***
2. Change the property **checked** into **[checked]**, otherwise the value is evaluating as a string instead of a boolean.

Try this

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="versioning" [checked]=”true” disabled>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `disabled` attribute like `[disabled]="isDisabled"`

toggle isDisabled to enable/disable the radio button.

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 mb-5">
  <label>Versioning</label><br/>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="versioning" value="Enabled" [(ngModel)]="selectedVal" >
    <label class="form-check-label">Enabled</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="versioning" checked="checked" [(ngModel)]="selectedVal" value="Disabled" [disabled]="isDisabled">
    <label class="form-check-label">Disabled</label>
  </div>
</div>
```